# Set Timeout Stop Loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a simple loop with set timeout that after some time, about 16 minutes, it stops working, I do not know why.
Do you have any idea why or a solution to understand what's wrong?

The code is very simple:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.interval = setInterval(this.function, interval);
}, delay);

function(){.....}
```

This repeat the function, but about 16 minutes stop to loop.

Comment: Does `delay` have a value (number)?

Comment: it should be `setInterval(function(){}, interval)` else it will throw error

Comment: it's a function that performs a check

Comment: Yes delay has a fixed number

Comment: What is happening in the function() ?

Comment: Check if a message is received

Comment: Do you get any error message in the console?

Comment: No nothing, that's why i don't know where is the problem

Comment: Have you checked memory consumption? Maybe you're running out of memory ..?

Comment: Yes. Most likely a memory issue.

Comment: i will check that thank you

Answer (score 0):

Current Code (As per assumption) :

```
function setData() { 
   for(var i=0;i<6;i++) { 
      setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)},3000)
   }
}
```

Suggested :

```
function setData(){
   for(var i=0;i<6;i++){ 
      settingData(i);
   }
}

function settingData(i){
  console.log(i);
}
```

As the setTimeOut runs in a separate context it will loose the initial values passed. Hence by migrating to separate function call it will not loose the context.

Comment: Place it in your answer so i can remove my votedown :)